# javascript + regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation

I have a problem. I want to use a regular expression that let me introduce just numbers and "." (for decimals) on an input field, no letters and other special character.

I'm trying this:

option 1 => `var restrict="[^\d+]"`

option 2 => `var restrict="[^\d+]"`

```
iAttrs.restrict = ^(?![0-9]+([.]?[0-9]+))$

value.toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp(iAttrs.restrict, 'g'), '');
```

This regular expression is an angular directive

```
appModule.directive('restrict', function($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                scope.$watch(iAttrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }
                    value = value.toString();
                    $parse(iAttrs.ngModel).assign(scope, value.toLowerCase().replace(new RegExp(iAttrs.restrict, 'g'), ''));
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

It must remove the wrong characters written on the input. But the problem is

option 1 ==> don't let me write "." character

option 2 ==> don't let me write nothing (when I have a default value example: "300.21" that must appear on the input field ... after restrict directive finish, nothing is written on the input.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape dot with \.

Comment: can you be a little more explicit? , how could be the regExp ? - Please

Comment: In regex, dot represents any character. So you must escape it with \ So replace dot with \. in your regex

Comment: Can you try this regex.. `/(\d*[\.])?\d+/`

Comment: No, you don't need to escape a dot that is inside square brackets.  The fact that the dot is part of a "range" means that it is no longer interpreted as an atom.  Try `echo "hello" | grep '[.]'` as a proof.

Comment: with : /(\d*[\.])?\d+/  ---->  don't work, the input field let write character's
for example --->  145.5r
and with option 1, doesn't let write characters but also ".", and i need let write "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Updated based on comments:

As the case for decimal point is very particular, I created a new directive for that.

Directive Code:

```
angular.module("app",[]).directive('allowOnlyDecimal', function($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                // used to find out if more than one . is available 
                function nth_ocurrence(str, needle, nth) {
                  for (i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
                    if (str.charAt(i) == needle) {
                      if (!--nth) {
                         return i;    
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  return false;
                }

                scope.$watch(iAttrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }
                    value = value.toString();
                    var temp = value.replace(/[^(\d\.)]/gi, '');
                    // this removes any special character and alphabets
                    if(nth_ocurrence(temp,".",2)) {
                      temp = temp.substr(0, nth_ocurrence(temp,".",2));
                      // removes if user enters more than one decimal point
                    }
                    scope[iAttrs.ngModel] = temp;
                });
            }
        };
}).controller("MainController", function($scope) {
       $scope.someInput = 100.400;
});
```

In your HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someInput" allow-only-decimal>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/soduwedeqe/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

> OLD ANSWER:

This could be more generic approach which you can use for most of the restrict functionality using regex.

HTML :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="someInput" restrict="[^(\d\.)]">
```

JS:

```
angular.module("app",[]).directive('restrict', function($parse, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch(iAttrs.ngModel, function(value) {
                if (!value) {
                    return;
                }
            value = value.toString();
            $timeout(function() {
               scope[iAttrs.ngModel] = value.replace(new RegExp(iAttrs.restrict,'gi'), '');


        },10);
            });
        }
    };
}).controller("MainController", function($scope) {
       $scope.someInput = 100.400;
});
```

Comment: This example is now working at all
it let you introduce text also into the input field

Comment: you are right MOHAMEDRIAS , but if you see, you can write also "$" and you can put more than one "."
did you see it ?
thanks

Comment: i Get the same with these regular expression  [^\d+\.*\d*$], but i don't understad why it let me write more than one "." and the point is that more than one "." can no't be accepted

Comment: Updated answer now. Created a new directive for this purpose as it's a special case for decimal number alone. For other generic emails and other scenario the previous solution will work.

Comment: can you give an idea how could it be ?
Thanks

Comment: an small example, how is possible put more than one directive into the same component. Up to now my input field has his directive "restric" and also a filter "currency" ... but how could be another for decimals ... 
Thanks

Comment: Updated answer now with comments

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple directives. Use priority to order the execution of them. Now you can remove restrict directive for this element. So this will have only currency and allow-only-decimal directive

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
^\d+\.*\d*$
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wN3oB3/1)**

[image]

Comment: This regExp works ... but when you continue writing into the input field, and write a second "." this regular expression let write it.  And the problem is that, there must not be permited write a second "." character
Any other idea.  Thanks

Comment: @julioVG the regex I provided you does not allow two `.`. I've updated my question with a working demo. I think you have missed adding something.

Comment: yes yes ... you are right, i get your regExp and test it on: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html

And it work's !!!  ... but when i use it on my directive, it let me write more than one "." character. (look link of image)

The error is ![valid XHTML][checkmark].
 
[checkmark]: http://postimg.org/image/3smfay55t/

Comment: @julioVG the regex is good but you might need to escape the backslashes. Try using `^\\d+\\.*\\d*$`